# Table inside media body is not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am having problem in viewing on small devices like mobile, the table inside in media body is not responsive in small devices.

Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading ">
   <h3 class="panel-title">
       Profile
   </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
       <div class="media">
             <div class="media-left">
               <a href="#">
                      <img class="media-object img-size160" src="images/officestaff.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                        <tr><td class="info" width="40%">Name</td><td>Jenny</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="info">Location</td><td>New york</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="info">Designation</td><td>Office staff</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="info">Status</td><td>Probitionary</td></tr>.
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
       </div>                           
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your `table-responsive` not on the `<table>`, but the `<div>`?

Comment: Per Bootstrap, *Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.* So if you're looking for something at 480 or smaller, it will not work and will always scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Per Bootstrap *Responsive tables by wrapping any `.table` in `.table-responsive` to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px).*

If you don't want to scroll horizontally, you can use `@media` queries to reformat your table. Here's a good example of how to do it. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php